# How to test unevaluated functions in clojure macros?

Tags: clojure, macros, eval

I want to evaluate if the argument to a macro is a function. If it is I would like to return the unevaluated function. Otherwise return a different function. Like so:

```
(defmacro func? [function]
  (if (fn? function)
     function
     identity))
((func? "oops") 5) ;=> 5 
((func? -) 5)      ;=> 5
```

However the above fails because the unevaluated function is not yet a *real function* to get this to work I must use the evil eval:

```
(defmacro func? [function]
  (if (fn? (eval function))
     function
     identity))
((func? "oops") 5) ;=> 5 
((func? -) 5)      ;=> -5
```

How do I avoid using eval here?
**Answer must be a macro.**

The reason for a macro over a function in my case is that this macro is used in a lot of functions that are called many times in my game. The macro is an output format interpreter. In other words I could write it myself to be that way, but the macro makes my code cleaner. If I used a function instead of this macro it would be doing this same interpretation, that only need be done once, about 60 times per 50ms iteration of my game. Hopefully that clarifies rather than clouding my situation.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  I can't help but think there's probably a better solution out there.

Comment: I apologize for failing to communicate my need for this function to be evaluated at compile time instead of at run-time. The question has been updated.

Comment: That help.  But what do you mean by "output format interpreter"?  Could you add some examples that show how you actually want to use this macro (in context)?  The examples you have don't make a lot of sense.  How does making `((func? "oops") 5)` evaluate to `5` relate to your "interpreter"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the many possible arguments to your macro in order to decide if it's a function or not.

1. Is it a symbol? A number? A string?
2. Symbol resolves to a var that is a function?
3. In what namespace that symbol needs to be resolved?

Assuming the functions to resolve live in the current namespace, you can do something like this:

```
(defn test
  []
  "result")

(defmacro func?
  [f]
  (if (and (symbol? f)
           (fn? (var-get (ns-resolve *ns* f))))
    f
    identity))

(func? test)
#object[user$test 0x37c27452 "prisma.server$test@37c27452"]

(func? 4)
#object[clojure.core$identity 0x3a811e64 "clojure.core$identity@3a811e64"]
```

Where `ns-resolve` and `var-get` gives you a handle to the proper function value (or whatever value for all the cases f is indeed a symbol resolving to something).

All functions resolved from the current namespace work, for instance:

```
(:require [some.ns :as other-ns])

(func? other-ns/valid-fn)
=> #object[some.ns$valid-fn 0x7207a00b "some.ns$valid-fn@7207a00b"]
```

Comment: [`resolve`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve) could be used in place of `ns-resolve` here.  Also, all macros take an implicit [`&env`](http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-and.html) argument, which should probably be consulted to handle locally-defined functions. Unfortunately, I don't think the details of `&env` is considered to be part of Clojure's public API.

Comment: In addition, you can simply use `deref` (or `@`) to dereference a `Var`.

Answer (score 2):

Why use a macro?

```
(defn func? [function]
  (if (fn? function)
     function
     identity))

((func? "oops") 5) ;=> 5 
((func? -) 5)      ;=> -5
```

---

Note that `#(identity %)` is just `identity`.

Comment: The above is a reduced example (Don't think anyone wants 200 lines pasted here) where I want to use macros because the change should only be called once  at compile time. Rather than being called multiple times during run-time.

Comment: @JasonBasanese You can probably close over the evaluation (in a `def` or a subsidiary `let`) to avoid repeating it. Unless you depend upon the *form* that yields the possible function, I can't see that it helps to frame the computation in a macro.

Comment: @JasonBasanese This makes sense. Your case reminds me of the role of  [predicates](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_predicates) in the new `clojure.spec`. But the question seems blinkered.  Perhaps you could contrive one that conveys your dilemma more openly.